# Android Emulator for development without Android Studio

Tags: linux, android-emulator

I need to test apps against specific versions of Android for development purposes and am looking for an emulator to do that. Here are the requirements:

- Must be 100% FOSS
- Must work on x86_64 Linux
- Must work and meet all requirements without Android Studio
- Must support arbitrary released versions of Android (save for some outdated ones), specifically Android 11
- Must have a somewhat user-friendly way of setting up a VM

  - GUI preferred
  - upon detecting an invalid configuration, the UI should inform me where the error is (e.g. option X requires option Y and cannot be used in combination with option Z) and allow me to correct the mistake without having to start from scratch
  - a well-documented text config file is also OK
- Should have decent performance (preferably emulating the same processor architecture as the host, i.e. x86_64)
- Should have the characteristics of a real device

What I’ve tried so far (and hasn’t worked for me):

- Android SDK emulator: GUI is no longer available and without Android Studio, the only way to set up an emulator is with a lengthy command line and answering pages of questions in a text-based GUI; one wrong answer and the system will abort with no further explanation, requiring you to restart from scratch (after guessing what option was the wrong one, and remembering all your settings from last time)
- Anbox: only supports Android 7, which is a deal breaker; as a minor bummer, and the window approach behaves very differently from a real device
- Android x86 in an emulator (e.g. VirtualBox): last version is Android 9 (vanilla) or LineageOS 14.1 (based on Android 7), which is a deal breaker; as a minor annoyance, mouse integration in VirtualBox is buggy

A decent configuration UI around the Android SDK emulator (just like the old AVD manager – or a way to get the AVD manager GUI back) or a good documentation on how to configure the Android SDK emulator will do as well.

Any pointers?

Comment: Did you ever find something to match these requirements?